# how to customize a button's size in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to resize a button as a square and here's my code:

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //method one 
    //button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:44.0).isActive = true
    //button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
    //method two
    button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonTapped(button: )), for: .touchUpInside)
    addArrangedSubview(button)
```

I have tried both method however none of them seem to work out fine with an error showing some mistakes in method one and nothing shown in method two. when i run the code, button is fulfilled in the container. what is wrong here?

Comment: Maybe u have some contraints that makes button size how it is ?

Comment: What is the error you're getting ? Also try setting constraints

Comment: if I am using stroyboard which means I dragged a button from library to stroyboard directly, I can set constraints conveniently. But now  I'm creating a button by coding. You see. the problem is that I cannot easily change button size now.

Comment: What do you do inside `addArrangedSubview` function? Only `view.addSubview(button)` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why not create the button and initialise it with the given size?

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
```

And then change the x and y accordingly

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work. I think the code is all right. there must be some more severe mistakes that cause the problem.

Comment: what is the result you get, please post the screenshot

Comment: also add a background color so that we can see the button

Comment: [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

Comment: Then you already have constraints to the button, Try creating another button with another name

Answer (score 6):

Use addSubview() instead of addArrangedSubview().

I write here the playground with the same solution I posted in comments, in case someone encounters the same problem:

**Swift 3.0:**

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 400))

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 20.0)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(button) // This does the trick

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```